# How to bring one application from default desktop to custom desktop?

Tags: c++, windows

Is there any way to bring one application from default desktop to custom desktop?

For example, CredentialUIBroker.exe(microsoft service) is always appear in default desktop(Winsta0\default).

I want to make this to appear in programmatically created new desktop.

Can you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: I'm guessing the name is hardcoded.